# Bootstrap validator tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, formularios, validación

Estoy validando mis formularios con boostrap validator (http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) y quedan asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaria que el mensaje no salga en la parte inferior, si no como un tooltip desde el icono algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo usar el plugin de form validation por cuestiones de licencia.

Comment: Está bien que añadas imágenes de cómo quieres que se vea y cómo se ve ahora mismo, pero también sería util que incluyeras un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Como estas poder hacerlo con jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip

Examples using data attributes

```
<input type="text" name="example1" required>
```

Examples using JavaScript

```
$("#theform").validate({
rules: {
example4: {email:true, required: true},
example5: {required: true}
},
messages: {
example5: "Just check the box<h5 class='text-danger'>You aren't going to read the EULA</h5>"
},
tooltip_options: {
example4: {trigger:'focus'},
example5: {placement:'right',html:true}
},
});
```

https://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/